# Basic 2D array comprehension

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I'm trying to understand why the following bit of Java code works properly. The main problem I'm having trouble wrapping my head around is the 2d array as an argument, so at `a[0][0]` what will be the `int` stored there given the test example below?

I'm also a tad confused as to why I don't need to define the array first then create it, then populate it with the argument.

```
public class Test {
    // returns the largest element in a 
    // e.g. max({{1, 3}, {7, -2, 0}, {4, 4}}) = 7
    public static int max(int[][] a) {
        int max = a[0][0];
        for (int[] r : a)
            for (int x : r)
                max = Math.max(max, x);
        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: woops sorry this is java

Answer (score 0):

1. `max` will be equal to 1 (first array is `{1,3}`, first item in that array is 1). The reason this is done is you need a first item for comparison, and there is no limitation as to what is the minimal value.
2. Since the array is given as a parameter in the function, the code that calls the function will populate the array.

Comment: Thanks but i'm still confused, perhaps if you could tell me what ints would be at : a [0][0]    a [0][1]       a [0][2]                                                                                                                                                                        a [1][0]    a [1][1]       a [1][2]........................i maybe able to infer from there and wrap my head around it a bit more.. thanks

Comment: Check this out: [nested arrays explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260531/explaining-nested-arrays-to-a-programmer)